# View content of an Azure Service Bus queue

Tags: azure, servicebus

I would like to see the messages (and their content) that are currently sitting in a queue waiting to be delivered. Does such a tool exist? Or should I write my own solution for this?

Comment: Does the Service Bus Explorer (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a) allow you to view Service Bus queue messages?  If not, the source code might provide a good base for adding queue message viewing.

Comment: Currently the Service Bus Queue only displays the count of the messages present and the total Size of the Queue. You cannot view the content of the message (browse the queue) since the only way to do that is to dequeue the message. One approach could be to peeklock a message, see its content and then Abandon the message (or let the lock expire) but during the locked period other readers cannot see that message.

Comment: @jmac the Service Bus Explorer doesn't seem to be able to have a look at the messages, but the source code might indeed be a good starting place for something custom

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We currently don't have a "browse" feature implemented for our queues that would allow you to do that. It's on the list of things to come.

Comment: After reviewing both azure's queue and amazon sqs I'd say it would be nice if azure had the ability to view all messages (without impacting visibility) or a view that would allow deleting.. Nice for testing purposes.

Comment: Six years later and still nothing?

Comment: I just went looking for this feature, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: six years later, still can't even purge a queue from your UI. Why?

Comment: @EdS.  This can be done with the Service Bus Explorer
https://chocolatey.org/packages/ServiceBusExplorer/

Comment: @mababin: yeah, I eventually found that, but it's frustrating how useless the azure portal is. All sorts of fancy UI in comparison to e.g. AWS, but not even close when it comes to functionality.

Comment: The chocolatey thing is windows only, all other solutions cost money. Great work microsoft.

Comment: Nearly 9 years later and still nothing. Sick!

Answer (score 32):

The new version of [Service Bus Explorer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a) supports browsing messages in a Queue without dequeueing them.

It makes use of the new [Peek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj908787.aspx) feature in Service Bus SDK 2.0

```
QueueClient queueClient = QueueClient.Create("myQ");
BrokeredMessage message = queueClient.Peek();
```

Comment: This link seems no more relevant :(

Comment: Jonathan [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Service-Bus-Explorer-f2abca5a) (one of the comment of the original question) seems better :  download C# ; unzip it; then got to "bin/debug" directory

Answer (score 6):

Azure Management Studio from Cerebrata also allows you to browse a service bus queue.  Note that this is not free.  The website is here:

http://www.cerebrata.com/

Answer (score 5):

Service bus explorer peek option allows you to view messages in the queue.
Messages->Peek->MessageText
[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of this writing, [Service Bus Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2015/03/02/service-bus-explorer-2-6-now-available.aspx) lets you peek or receive messages in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

New service called [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) from folks who created AzureWatch (and whom I'm affiliated with) can monitor contents of the "next" message in the ASB (or storage) queue and surface it for monitoring/alerting/scaling purposes

Answer (score 0):

The **Service Bus Queue** in Azure Portal has **Service Bus Explorer** option in the menu and it allows you to browse the queue.

It seems the desktop application mentioned in other answers has been discontinued and instead the explorer has been integrated into the Azure portal.

[image]