# Pattern to determine if a specific message is still queued in an Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a pusher which brokers message x into an Azure Service bus. This is a customer request for some order.

A consumer comes along and wants to know "what is the state of message x"? I'd like to know as much as I can about message x, but at a minimum I need to answer "yes/no" is it still in the queue? Is there a recommended pattern for this within Azure Service Bus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [View content of an Azure Service Bus queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043219/view-content-of-an-azure-service-bus-queue) Clemens Vasters explains that there is no browse feature available in Service Bus Queues/Topics at the moment. The only way to know the state is by storing it externally (take Table Storage for example).